# Why isn't my Jest spy showing as called when I can see that it is?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to determine why exactly my Jest spy isn't being called when I can see that the spy is properly "injected" into my component?  Here's my very simple example:

**TestComponent.js**

```
export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event && event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleSubmit called!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <button className="submit-button" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**TestComponent.test.js**

```
describe("TestComponent tests", () => {
  it("`handleSubmit` is called when form is submitted", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleSubmit");

    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

If I do a `console.log` on the `wrapper.instance().handleSubmit` I can clearly see that the spy has been injected into the object's property, yet my test still fails stating that the spy was not called.

A CodeSandbox with a working example can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3ymkp3w5x1

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the onSubmit function is somehow getting called asynchronously -- going to do some more research in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is not to test that `handleSubmit` was called, but just to check for the results of calling `handleSubmit`.  Having said that...

---

### Issue

`onSubmit` is bound directly to the value of `this.handleSubmit` at the time the component renders.

---

### Solution

Use a lambda function (note, [this might cause performance issues](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render)) so that `onSubmit` calls the current value of `this.handleSubmit` when it is invoked:

```
<form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
```